# Why does this code have issues with the CGI module?

Tags: perl, module, cgi

Good morning, I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use LWP::Simple;
use List::Util qw/min max sum/;

my $urlData = "http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/~ullrich/data.pl";
my $title   = "Statistical analysis of weather data for a particular date";
#
# Display form with input fields
# Take a CGI object as input
#
```

etc ...

```
print $q->end_html;
```

I cannot run this code because a warning about the modules pops up, but it seemed to be OK. Any idea about what's going on?

First, the CGI module, but when I comment that one out, the following modules also cause the same error message.

This is the error message I receive

> Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5 /vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at main.pl line 5. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at main.pl line 5

I tried running in an online compiler and got an error. Will this be solved by installing those missing modules in the computer before compiling? Which IDE do you recommend to test this code?

**tl;dr** **The solution is below:** I needed to install the missing modules.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach that before. This is the error message I receive: Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5
/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at main.pl line 5.                                                                                                            
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at main.pl line 5.

Comment: The CGI module is not installed

Comment: So, I guess this is because the compiler cannot locate the CGI module, right?

Comment: Is there any online compiler which could run this code?

Comment: I do not know. I do not know any online compiler

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, I could install Padre or another IDE to run the code? I use Windows.

Comment: You do not Need an IDE. You must install the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear to me:

> Can't locate CGI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CGI module)

Which version of Perl are you using? CGI.pm was a core Perl module from 5.004 to 5.20. From 5.22 onwards, CGI.pm has been removed from the Perl core distribution. You will need to install it separately.

But it's worth considering the reason why CGI.pm was removed from the Perl core - it's because it isn't the recommended way to write web applications with Perl in 2017. I recommend reading [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for an overview of some more modern technologies.

However, as you already have a CGI program, I'm assuming that you don't want to rewrite it all from scratch to reflect modern Perl best practices. I would, however, urge you to remove the use of the HTML generation functions from your code. We've known they are a terrible idea since the end of the last millennium and [they are now deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used). Please consider moving your HTML generation into some kind of template (there's an example using the Template Toolkit in the CGI::Alternatives document I mentioned above).

You are also using subroutine prototypes. Their use is also strongly discouraged unless you are using one of the small number of cases where they add useful functionality. I'd recommend removing them.

**Update:** In your comment, you say:

> what I didn't get is why I was missing so many modules "apparently".

Looking at the list of modules in your code:

- CGI was added to core in 5.004 and removed in 5.22.
- CGI::Carp was added and removed at the same times as CGI.
- LWP::Simple has never been in the Perl core distribution. But from Perl 5.14, the core has included HTTP::Tiny which does many of the same things.
- List::Util has been in the Perl core since 5.8.

So I think that mainly your problem was assuming that more libraries are in the core than actually are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. You see, I hadn't coded in Perl before... what I didn't get is why I was missing so many modules "apparently". Now, I understand why. Unfortunately, I cannot redo all the work because I just have little time to check how it works. But I will note that down as a coding exercise or the future. I really appreciate your insight here @Dave Cross.

Comment: Re "*what I didn't get is why I was missing so many module*", Basically, Perl comes with the modules it needs to install other modules, and a few others for historical reasons. That's pretty much it.